# Create a vertex between two other (selected) vertices - a set distance from either of the selected vertices

Tags: vertices

I cannot find the add-on for this feature. I cannot find an inbuilt function for this feature. Am I going to have to build this add-on myself?

There is an add-on which works on a percentage basis but I don't like this.

Comment: storme  ... No matter how misguided you might think they are, and no matter how justified your opinion, please don't be rude to folks who are trying to help you, for nothing. Please find a polite and kind way to correct them.

Comment: @storme You mention an add-on for percentage that you don't like, so I just informed you, for percentage you wouldn't need an add-on. And guess what, the vertex I moved in my example had to be created beforehand by subdividing an edge. But don't worry, I won't bother you anymore with any comment or answer in the future, no matter how helpful it might be.

Comment: Follow the link to download my add-on that does what I ask. https://github.com/Storme9/vertex_insert